# Problem Accessing Project With Azure DevOps

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a project on dev.azure.com. I can access this project under normal conditions.

I have defined a new team member when I check it from the visual studio via team explorer,
the person I added as a member cannot see the project.
Later, I added the user I added as administrators in the project, but still, we could not see the project.
I'm trying to add the project manually on the Add Azure DevOps Server page, but it gives an error like on the screen.

The user is a member of the project and added as an admin, so why can't I see the project?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Has the user gone through the "Accept invite" email and did you assign an appropriate license (you can check the license status in the users tab)?

Comment: In case the Azure DevOps org is AAD backed, did the user pick the "School or work account" option when signing in? The organization won't show up when the user picked "Personal", even though you're trying to log on with an `@outlook.com` identity (and vice versa).

Comment: I thought nothing else was needed when I added it to the project members. I saw that it is not included in the users section in the Organization section. My problem was solved when I added here. 
Thank you

Comment: The user does have to exist in the organization before you can give them access to a project. @jessehouwing is also correct in that the user has to have the appropriate license set up and signin type. You have two options for getting the user in your org - 1) as you did, go to Organization settings -> Users and add them, or 2) create Group Rules under Organization settings -> Users, and add a rule that maps an AD group to the project(s) you want to authorize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought nothing else was needed when I added it to the project members. I saw that it is not included in the users section in the Organization section.
My problem was solved when I added here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he is missing license or add him in permission tab to group contributor or project valid user.